# Why Cannot I access my website on my apache2 server?

Tags: apache2, vhosts

On an apache2 server, I recently cloned an app 'MyApp' from github. But I'm not able to access it through url `133.29.22.57/MyApp/` (ip address is dummy) ? I have tried setting permissions for `/var/www/` folder to 777, I also created a new file `myapp.conf` in `etc/apache2/sites-available/` , then I used `a2ensite` to make it live, then restarted server but still can't access the site. Please help.
Here are the contents of my `myapp.conf` file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/MyApp/

        <Directory /var/www/MyApp/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Some (possibly) relevant info from **apache2.conf**

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

**UPDATE** 
some of the content that you may find relevant which I found under `/var/log/apache2/access.log`...

```
169.149.128.75 - - [20/Mar/2017:12:30:49 +0000] "GET /MyApp HTTP/1.1" 404 497 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
169.149.128.75 - - [20/Mar/2017:12:31:01 +0000] "GET /MyApp/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
169.149.128.75 - - [20/Mar/2017:12:31:05 +0000] "GET /MyApp/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 506 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
169.149.128.75 - - [20/Mar/2017:12:31:40 +0000] "GET /MyApp/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 507 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [20/Mar/2017:12:36:02 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 125 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21 (internal dummy connection)"
```

moreover,

I tried running command `/usr/sbin/apache2 -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`

which says that the following variables are not defined :

```
 ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} ${APACHE_PID_FILE } ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP  } ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting permissions for `/var/www/` folder to `777` is a **very bad habit**.

Give the directory (recursive) to the web server user, usually `www-data` like "`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`"

Then do a separated log, something like "`mywebsite.error.log`" and "`mywebsite.access.log`" so you'll be able to see quickly what's going on.

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite.error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite.access.log combined
```

Then tell us more precisely what's going on and I'll update my answer.

Comment: I cant. The information you added are not relevant enough. With what you've given all we can infer is (1) `/MyApp` gives a 404 and (2) `/MyApp/index.php` gives a 404 too. We need the rewriterule log you can have with `mywebsite.access.log` or with the `mywebsite.error.log` (depending on the apache version). We need the rewriterule log so we can see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Did you activate the mod_rewrite by the way?